# fourier series expansion show that:

Tags: fourier-series

I have a problem that I've partially worked but don't understand the next part/have made a mistake?

$f(x)=0$ for $-\pi< x<0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $0≤x≤\pi$

I have $a_0=\dfrac \pi 4$ and $a_n=0$ and $b_n=0$ if n is even and $b_n=\dfrac 2 n$ if $n$ is odd

so.... $$f(x)= \frac π 4 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{2n+1})  \sin[(2n+1) π x]$$

Now I need to show $$\frac π 4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 \dots$$ using suitable values of $x$.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac 1 \pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$
$$\frac 1 \pi \int_{0}^\pi x\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\cos\pi n -1}{\pi n^2}$$
So:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\pi n -1}{\pi n^2}
\cos(nx)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos[\pi (2n+1)] -1}{\pi (2n+1)^2}\cos[(2n+1)x]$$
$$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi (2n+1)^2}\cos[(2n+1)x]$$

Similarly:
$$b_n=-\frac{\pi\cos(n\pi)}{n}=-\frac{\pi(-1)^n}{n}$$

Finally $$f(x)=\frac \pi 4 -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi (2n+1)^2}\cos[(2n+1)x] -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nx) $$

Let $x= \pi /2$ this way we'll cancel out the terms containing cosine. In addition, the right-most sum will be null if $n$ is even so we're left with:
$$\frac \pi 2=\frac \pi 4 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\sin[(2n+1) \frac \pi 2]$$
etc.